# Postfix - "Illegal address syntax": send error notification

Tags: postfix

Sometimes Outlook users send email through our Postfix mail server with malformed "to" field, with quotes in it:

'recipient@domain.com'

and Postfix writes "warning: Illegal address syntax" error in logs, but it does not send a non delivery notification. But if I send an email to a malformed address from command line on Postfix server, root user receives the non delivery notification.
Is it possible to notify a remote sender, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI I asked on Postfix mailing list and the answer is:

> No. When an SMTP server does not accept a message, it is the
>   responsibility of the SMTP client to inform the sender that email
>   was not accepted.